# Best way to insert . or , in an integer when displaying money

Tags: php, currency, laravel-5.6

I have an integer `1000` - I would like to show it to the users as 10.00

I am wondering the best solution/practice for this?

**Have tried the following, but none of these are the desired result:**

```
<?php
echo number_format("1000")."<br>";
echo number_format("1000",2)."<br>";
echo number_format("1000",2,",",".");
?>
```

**Outputs the following:**

```
1,000
1,000.00
1.000,00
```

Comment: Why not just print the number/100 ? Assuming you have stored the number of cents and want do display the actual value

Comment: Why would an integer 1000 be presented as 10.00

Comment: Without more details it is impossible to answer. What do you display `10000000000` as? `10.00.000.00.00`? `100000000.00`? `1.00.00.00.00.00`? `100,000,000.00`?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php ?

Comment: In what locale is a separator inserted after two digits…?

Comment: @deceze Eh, brain fart, I misremembered stuff. But not too far from [reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).

Comment: thanks for the answers, could number/100 produce rounding? if the INT was 9999 or other odd numbers? (or am i having a brain fart on Monday morning)

Comment: I guess i am hoping there is a function that splits string_length > 3 and adds the . and if string_length > 5 it would add a ,

Comment: Then go for `number_format($number/100, 2, '.', ',');` (still assuming you stored the cents value) (Try it: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b88c2cde48f235bfad78edd81b26718f0aead620)